# Bazel on Windows: Error: couldn't connect to server after 60 seconds

Tags: windows, tensorflow, bazel

I hope you can help me with my problem. I'm trying to build a Tensorflow v r0.12 from sources with GPU support on Windows 8.1.
Every action I do (including even "bazel clean", "bazel fetch" and "bazel info release") leads to ~600 dots and this error:
"Error: couldn't connect to server after 60 seconds"
Anybody have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Quote from official website (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup.html)
"Installing from sources...
To build TensorFlow from source on Windows, you can use experimental support for Bazel on Windows or the TensorFlow CMake build."

Comment: Bazel support on Windows is ["highly experimental"](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/windows.html). The [CMake build for TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake) is more reliable at present, although we're aiming to move to using Bazel as soon as the kinks have been worked out.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly possible that you are not setting the right environment variables.
Use `where msys-2.0.dll` to ensure your PATH is set up correctly.